# How to add time estimates

Tags: probability, skewness

Imagine I have a bunch at tasks to complete sequentially. There is some uncertainty about how long each task will take to complete. So for each task, we might estimate a 50% chance that it can be completed in less than `t` days, a 90% chance that it can be completed in less than `t + x` days, and only a 10% chance that it can be completed in less than `t - y` days.

Since no task can be completed in less than O days, the probability distribution for each task is right skewed.

How can I calculate the number of days required to complete all of the tasks, with 10%, 50% and 90% certainty (or rather, estimated probability)? So I want to find some `T`, `X` and `Y`, such that there is a 10% chance that all of the tasks can be completed in less than `T - Y` days, a 50% chance that they will all be completed in less than `T` days and a 90% char a that they win be completed in less than `T + X` days.

I'd also like to understand the answer, so an explanation (or a link to one) would be appreciated... Thanks in advance.

Comment: So I think [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158240/how-to-calculate-the-time-of-finishing-all-tasks-with-probability-of-90?rq=1) is pretty much the same, except that it doesn't explicitly state or account for the fact that the distribution will be right skewed...